# Bootstrap vertical spacing between divs and carousel

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I'm building a new website using bootstrap 5 and there's a vertical spacing between my divs. The top div contains a carousel and the bottom one has a heading at the top. The carousel extends longer than the containing div, however all the pictures are the same size 1080x1920.  I don't know what I should do to fix this.

```css
.top-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.top-container .carousel-slide .carousel-fade {
  display: block;
}

.middle-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #F9EBE0;
}

.middle-container h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: red;
}

.navbar {
  background: #210B2C;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <!-- link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-geWF76RCwLtnZ8qwWowPQNguL3RmwHVBC9FhGdlKrxdiJJigb/j/68SIy3Te4Bkz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!--html for bootstrap navbar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-lg">
    <div class="container-fluid navbar-custom">
      <a class="navbar-brand nav-name" href="#">Cam</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Projects</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">About Me</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="https://github.com/CamShoward">Github</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <!--html for bootstrap caurosel-->
  <div class="top-container">
    <div id="carouselExampleFade" class="carousel slide carousel-fade">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1080x1920" class="d-block w-100 img-fluid" alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1080x1920" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1080x1920" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleFade" data-bs-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
        </button>
      <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleFade" data-bs-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="text-center middle-container">
    <h1 class="greeting-name">Hi I'm Cameron</h1>
    <h4>Welcome to my website </h4>
    <p>Welcome to my online portfolio, here you'll find references to all my projects and other work.
    </p>

    <h2>Highlighted Work</h2>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Does the demo above show the problem? Please revise as needed.

Comment: FYI, your custom stylesheet should be loaded _after_ Bootstrap's stylesheet so you can properly override any Bootstrap styles.